# About arrays and printing out the newly sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code for reversing the order of an array:

```
int array[x];
String temp;

String reversedOrder = "";

for (int i = 0; i < x/2; i++)
 {
 temp = array[i];
 array[i] = array[x-1 - i];
 array[x-1 - i] = temp;
 reversedOrder = reversedOrder + array[i];
 }
System.out.println(reversedOrder);
```

My question is how to print out this newly sorted array? I try to declare a string and put it in the for loop but it doesnt print the way I wanted it to: lets say "Hello World I am here" I need it to print out "olleHdlroWImaereh" but all it prints are first two reversed words "olleHdlroW" and ends right there.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

*I am trying to write this program out on my OWN free time.

*Thanks to everyone for helping me with my program. It finally worked after adding a for loop similar to Elliot's. :p cheers.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo reverseOrder is a string (well, one time is reversedOrder then reverseOrder)

Comment: You're concatenating only first `x/2` elements of array, when you should concatenate `x`.

Comment: Is my logic correct? what about reversedOrder = reversedOrder + array[i] part?

Comment: qiu I tried doing that first but it just repeated: "olleHdlroWIdlroWolleH"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easiest way is to use [Arrays#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29). Secondly, there are a few problems with your code,

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 }; // <-- your array declaration isn't valid.
// String temp; // <-- A String is not an int.
int x = array.length; // <-- added to demonstrate

for (int i = 0; i < x / 2; i++) {
    // This is a swap with no temporary storage, also known as the
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm
    array[i] ^= array[x - 1 - i];
    array[x - 1 - i] ^= array[i];
    array[i] ^= array[x - 1 - i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output is

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

**EDIT**

Remove the Arrays.toString(), and replace it with something like this -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : array) {
    sb.append(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output is

```
321
```

**EDIT 2**

Or, you could use

```
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
System.out.println();
```

Which will also output

```
321
```

Comment: Ok but I dont want the output to be [3,2,1] but 321. Is there a way to put the arrays together?

Comment: is there a way to not use StringBuilder? Thanks again.

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp See my edit 2 above, but also yes.

Comment: Elliot u are amazing. :p     but what if I am trying to "return" a varialbe like a string. In my example it would be "return array;" but if I tried to use system.out.println with for loop from your answer, I would think that will not work with that circumstance. What do u recommend? Sorry for all the questions. I promise this will be the last one. I just want to get this out of the way instead of creating another thread

Comment: Use the StringBuilder. That is what it's for. Even if you did "String arithmetic" the JVM would make it a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays` class to print user friendly string of `array`

```
Arrays.toString(array);
```

Try this one:

```
    String[] array = new String[] { "Hello", "World", "I", "am", "here" };

    String[] newArray = new String[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[array.length - 1 - i] = new StringBuilder(array[i]).reverse().toString();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

--EDIT--

Use this one to print out `array` in string format without any commas and brackets

```
    String str = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(", ", "");
    System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
```

Comment: ah I just saw your edit. I will try that along with all the other answers

Comment: I have updated my post to print out array in string format without any commas and brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse logic looks correct, however you are trying to append your reversedOrder string as you traverse only half of the charArray.

You can get your entire reversed charArray as a String by using the `String(char[])` constructor after the for loop.

```
@Test
public void reverse() {
  char[] charArray = "Hello World I am here".toCharArray();
  int x = charArray.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < x/2; i++) {
    char temp = charArray[i];
    charArray[i] = charArray[x-1 - i];
    charArray[x-1 - i] = temp;
  }

  String expected = "ereh ma I dlroW olleH";
  assertEquals(expected, new String(charArray));
}
```